# I want to perform the following Statements in Excel only on certain condition

Tags: excel, if-statement, conditional-statements, cells

NOTE: AN4 an AO4 cell format are Date short

I am doing the following:

Column BK:

```
=IF(AN4<AO4,"LATE","Ontime")
```

Very simple I agree BUT I want to execute that statement only when:

AN4 and AO4 are not empty

ALSO

If AN4 has a date but AO4 is Empty, I want to write in column BK: In Delivery

If AN4 & AO4 are Empty, I want to write in column BK: Order in Process

Comment: Will the dates all be formatted the same? If so, how?

Comment: I finally found the perfect formula:

Comment: =IF(AND(AN6="",AO6<>""),"ENTRY ERROR",IF(AN6="","Order in Progress",IF(AND(AN6<>"",AO6=""),"In Delivery",IF(AN6=AO6,"Ontime",IF(AN6<AO6,"Late",IF(AN6>AO6,"Early","XXX"))))))

 
A friend found it for me after I was almost loosing my mind :)

Comment: Did your even try any that we gave?  The "ENTRY ERROR" Was not in your original post.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use nested IF statements like:

```
=IF(AND(AN4="",AO4=""),"Order in Process",IF(AO4="","In Delivery",IF(AN4<AO4,"LATE","Ontime")))
```

So it basically tests if each is false it moves to test the next one.

Comment: How do you check if `AN4` has a date? I was going to search for "/" in a cell, but am waiting to see how dates are formatted.

Comment: @BruceWayne its in the OP `NOTE: AN4 an AO4 cell format are Date short`

Comment: Then I guess we're assuming that if there's *any* value in `AN4`, it's going to be a date?  Mainly just wondering if there should be some `if an4 = date format` type check, but it sounds like it'd be just superfluous, since you can just check if it's empty or not.

Comment: @BruceWayne and it does not matter because the OP "Found" his own answer without checking any of these.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use Value function to check if value exists and then compare, used nested IF:

```
    =IF(AND(VALUE(D4) = 0, VALUE(F5) = 0), "", IF(AND(VALUE(D4) >0,VALUE(F5) > 0), IF(D4<F5, "late", "ontime"),IF(VALUE(D4)>0, "In Delivery", "Order in process")))
```